# Apply Two gems to a form object in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, rubygems

Let's say I have two gems, `styling` and `logicSearch`

Each can be applied to a `form_for` in the following ways:

`<%= styling_form_for @sample do |f| %>`

and

`<%= logicSearch_form_for @sample do |f| %>`

However, what if I want to apply BOTH to the form? The styling changes, *and* the logic changes. Is there a way for me to apply two gems/methods to the same form object?

EDIT: To answer questions: No, I am not authoring these gems myself. Both are 3rd-Party.

Comment: Are you authoring these gems (you have more options, then!), or are you using them? There's not going to be a super-neat way to do this. You could override parts of `ActionView::Helpers::FormHelper` and provide your own form_for method that picks and chooses methods from the two gems. It's an interesting question though.

Comment: If you were authoring the gems yourself I wouldn't create form_for variations that specialized in styling/special logic at all.

Comment: You could look into a specialized `FormBuilder`--this is what `form_for` uses to create elements--take a look at the docs here http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder.html

Answer (score 2):

Hard to answer without knowing the actual gems you're talking about, but my guess is that you'd have to locate the form builders inside the gems, and see if you can create your own builder that mixes features of both.

Then :

```
 <%= form_for @sample, builder: MyMixedBuilder do |f| %>
```

see [FormBuilder's doc](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder.html) for additional details.